# Subtracting two columns within a Pandas GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with marketing campaigns, where each house receive campaign actions like "flyer", or "call". Each action has it's own creation and end date. Some houses have only 1 action, and some have a couple.

What I want to do is:

I want to calculate the length of the campaign for each house, so the time between the first action (e.g. flyer) and the last recorded action for each house. If each house had only 1 action, I could easily solve this by subtracting the end date column with the start date column.

Because some houses have multiple actions, I figured I could group all the houses with the Pandas GroupBy function. Does anyone know how to subtract within a groupby object?

Data looks like this:

```
house1 flyer 01-12-2014 05-12-2014
house1 phonecall 06-12-2014 06-12-2014
house2 flyer 01-12-2014 31-12-2014
```

my expected output looks like this:

```
house1 ; 5 days
house2 ; 30 days
house3 ; 12 days
house4 ; 60 days
etc
```

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: added expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the `agg` function on groups:

```
t = df.groupby("house").agg({"start": min, "end": max})
t["duration"] = t.end - t.start
```

The result is:

```
            start        end duration
house                                
house1 2014-01-12 2014-06-12 151 days
house2 2014-01-12 2014-12-31 353 days
```

#### Edit - creating the dataframe

Per a question in one of the comments, here's how I created the dataframe:

```
data = """house1 flyer 01-12-2014 05-12-2014
house1 phonecall 06-12-2014 06-12-2014
house2 flyer 01-12-2014 31-12-2014"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = "\s+", 
                 header = None, 
                 names = ["house", "medium", "start", "end"])

# Make sure 'start' and 'end' are dates. 
df.end = pd.to_datetime(df.end)
df.start = pd.to_datetime(df.start)
```

Comment: I think this will work, but I get the error message "str object has no attribute 'agg' ".
I think this could be due to the dates being in a datetime format.

Comment: indeed, it seems to be an issue with your dataframe. I'll add the code I used to create the dataframe from the text above.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed an issue with the column name. 
This solution worked!